# ¿Se puede retornar un print o un mensaje en python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

si en una funcion puedo retornar un print o el mensaje en si que me piden dar, el ejercicio dice que si el numero esta dentro de la lista debe decirle al usuario que tal valor si esta en la lista y lo mismo en caso contrario.

```
def comprobarEnLista(L):
    print"Ingrese el numero que desea saber si esta o no en la lista"
    n=int(raw_input("Numero a comprobar: "))
    L=[]
    i=0
    while i<len(L):
       for cont in L:
          if n==L[i]:
             print "El valor %d esta en la lista"%n
          else:
             print"El valor %d no esta en la lista"%n
    i+=1
```

Esa es la funcion en si que estoy creando , si me pudieran ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: También puedes hacer una función súper simple escribiendo `return n in L `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, tus prints están bien hechos. El resto de la función, más bien no.

Puedes comprobar fácilmente si n esta en L con `n in L`. Esto devuelve True si esta en la lista, o False en caso contrario.

```
def comprobarEnLista(L):
    print"Ingrese el numero que desea saber si esta o no en la lista"
    n=int(raw_input("Numero a comprobar: "))
    if n in L:
        print "El valor %d esta en la lista"%n
    else:
        print "El valor %d no esta en la lista"%n
```

Comment: Gracias de nuevo por quitarme las dudas uwu disculpa las molestias por estas preguntas

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo tu problema, ya estás haciendo print. El print no se puede retornar pero con ejecutarlo ya se imprime en consola

Puedes retornar un mensaje.

En tu código veo varios problemas, el i+=1 está fuera del while así que nunca incrementa y el bucle es infinito, nunca se detiene, utilizar dos bucles es realmente inecesaeio e ineficiente con uno ya valía:

```
def comprobarEnLista(L):
    print"Ingrese el numero que desea saber si esta o no en la lista"
    n=int(raw_input("Numero a comprobar: "))
    for z in L:
        if z == n:
           return "El valor %d esta en la lista"%n
        else:
           return "El valor %d no esta en la lista"%n
```

Pero la forma más eficiente es hacerlo con un if:

```
def comprobarEnLista(L):
    print"Ingrese el numero que desea saber si esta o no en la lista"
    n=int(raw_input("Numero a comprobar: "))
    if n in L:
       return "El valor %d esta en la lista"%n
    else:
       return "El valor %d no esta en la lista"%n
```

Con if in compruebas si un elemento está dentro de una lista

CUÁNTAS VECES SE REPITE UN VALOR EN LA LISTA

Suponiendo L es la lista y N el número que se quiere ver cuántas veces se repite

```
def cuantas_veces_repite(L, N):
     return L.count(N)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder mi duda, era solo eso de saber como podia entregar esos mensajes en pantalla, este codigo es nuevo para mi y por eso me confundo hehe ^^ disculpa pero me podrias decir como seria en el caso de que me pidieran decir cuantas veces se repitio el numero en la lista? disculpa las molestias u.u

Comment: Te lo he añadido en mi respuesta, espero te sirva, saludos